# Get the last 10 objects in arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm trying to obtain the last 10 objects within an `arraylist`.

Case: `Arraylist` full of `objects[ChartObjectsInt]` and `[ChartObjectsReal]` with indexes from 0-N, i want to obtain the last 10 persons (N-10), and with these last 10 objects I want to call functions from that object; like `ChartObjectsInt.getLabelName();`

Can anyone help?

Code I've reached so far:

```
private void getLastTenObjects()
{  
    foreach (ChartObjectsInt chartRecords in arraylistMonitor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arraylistMonitor.IndexOf(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't want to use LINQ at all**

```
for (var i = Math.Max(arraylistMonitor.Count - 10, 0); i < arraylistMonitor.Count; i++)
{
    YourFunctionCallHere(arraylistMonitor[i]);
}
```

*The above code will loop through the last 10 items of the `ArrayList` by setting `i` to the appropriate starting index - the `Math.Max` call there is in case the `ArrayList` has 9 or fewer elements in it.*

**If you are willing to use LINQ**

```
var last10 = arraylistMonitor.Cast<object>().Reverse().Take(10);
```

will do what you want. *You may also wish to add `ToList` after `Take(10)`, depending on how you wish to consume `last10`.*

Firstly it casts it to an `IEnumerable<object>` then goes through the `IEnumerable` backwards until it has (up to) 10 items.

If you **specifically** want `last10` to be an `ArrayList` (which I wouldn't recommend) then use:

```
var last10 = new ArrayList(arraylistMonitor.Cast<object>().Reverse().Take(10).ToList());
```

Comment: If i want to use the one where i dont use LINQ, i cant acces the methods of the objects in the arraylist.

Comment: That is the nature of an `ArrayList` @NielsSchutte . It is not typed (unlike a `List<T>`).

Comment: One option would be to replace `YourFunctionCallHere(arraylistMonitor[i]);` with `dynamic hello = arraylistMonitor[i]; YourFunctionCallHere(dynamic);`. `dynamic` will allow you to access the methods of the objects in the arraylist.

Comment: Or use my LINQ solution but change `Cast<object>` to `OfType<WhateverTypeYouWant>`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use List rather than ArrayList, if you do so it will be more easy to get last 10 element from list.

example:
var lastTenProducts = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductDate).Take(10);

//here products is the List

Comment: The arraylist is filled with multiple objects, not just "person" for example

Comment: @NielsSchutte `List<object>` will still work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, I would use `List<T>` as `ArrayList` is effectively deprecated for that as it exists from a time when C# didn't have generics.

With that said, you could write a function that would work for a list of any size and take however many like so

```
 public List<T> GetLastX<T>(List<T> list, int amountToTake)
 {
     return list.Skip(list.Count - amountToTake).ToList();
 }
```